# VBS - Getting program files folder path?

Tags: vbscript

I am tring to get program files folder in vbs. Tried this without luck;

```
SET wsc = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
SET fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
targetpath = wsc.SpecialFolders("ProgramFiles") & "\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

It just get the C:\ dir. What is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: Should be tagged `vbscript` only. However, instead of `targetpath = wsc.SpecialFolders("ProgramFiles") & ...` try `targetpath = wsc.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles%") & ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156616.aspx) article shows the list of SpecialFolders. Program Files is not among them. This is a limitation of the Windows Script Host. In the same way that the following shows a blank popup

```
SET wsc = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
msgbox wsc.SpecialFolders("Awesome")
```

So instead you have at least 2 options.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(&H26&)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
msgbox objFolderItem.Path
```

- &H26& - Program Files
- &H2A& - Program Files (x86)

The other option that I would offer is to use Environment variables like JosefZ suggests.

```
targetpath = wsc.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles%") & "..."
targetpath = wsc.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles(x86)%") & "..."
```

Comment: It's OK to include alternatives that were already suggested by someone else (particularly when they were only provided as a comment), as long as there is proper attribution.